# Change user password on Azure AD B2C using Microsoft Graph + Http Client

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, dotnet-httpclient

I've this code...

```
public class PasswordProfile { 
        public bool forceChangePasswordNextSignIn { get { return false; } }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
protected async Task setPasswords(string newP)
    {
        PasswordProfile newPassword = new PasswordProfile()
        {
            password = newP
        };
        var content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(newPassword), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", appToken);
        var update = await Http.PatchAsync($"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userUUID}", content);
    }
```

I can do this scenario using Postman. I just set the method to patch, put the json as body and it works good by returning a 204 and the password realy changed.

However my code return a 404. Any clue ?

Comment: 404 means not found, so either the URL you are calling using doesn't match the one in postman, or the user you are trying to change is wrong, or some other 'not found'.

Comment: Yep, @Nikki9696 ! Depending of the web server or backend, a 405 can happens as well.

Comment: So ok what's userUUID value coming from in your string interpolation thing there?

Comment: The same..I just copy/pasted on postman. Postman executes fine with the very same URL, using PATCH as method...but httpclient...not really :( It's throws 404 sadly

Comment: Weird. I guess if it were me, I'd double check with debugger that the ID was the same as I thought it was and the content was what I thought it was. Sometimes I'm surprised when I could have sworn it was the same and something else wasn't getting set that I just SWORE I set.

Comment: Oh, also for grins pop a debug breakpoint there and look at what the response is. Might be some weird auth error disguised as a 404. I've seen that happen.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `JsonSerializer.Serialize(newPassword)` it returns the following json

```
{
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false,
    "password": "xWwvJ]6NMw+bWH-d"
}
```

but Graph API [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-3-update-the-passwordprofile-of-a-user-to-reset-their-password) expects json like this

```
{
  "passwordProfile": {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false,
    "password": "xWwvJ]6NMw+bWH-d"
  }
}
```

You can create a new class `User` with `PasswordProfile` property and serialize an instance of `User` class.

```
public class User
{
    public PasswordProfile passwordProfile { get; set; }
}

protected async Task setPasswords(string newP)
{
    var user = new User
    {
        passwordProfile = new PasswordProfile
        {
            password = newP
        }
    }
    var content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(user), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", appToken);
    var update = await Http.PatchAsync($"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userUUID}", content);
}
```